# Combine 2 rows into one row, Using 2 columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRnVt.png)

However, the issue is that instead of saying that Patricia has 13 tickets and 1 movie ticket in the same row, it's separating into different rows.

I think I need to be doing a pivot table, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to be doing.

This is my code so far:

```
    select customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email,
count(ticketdetails.eventtype) as 'Theater Tickets',
0 as 'Movie Tickets'
from customer
inner join ticketdetails on ticketdetails.hippcode = customer.hippcode
where ticketdetails.hippcode is not null
and ticketdetails.eventType ='T'
Group by Customer.hippcode
union 
select customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email,
0, count(ticketdetails.eventtype) as 'Movie Tickets'
from customer
inner join ticketdetails on ticketdetails.hippcode = customer.hippcode
where ticketdetails.hippcode is not null
and ticketdetails.eventType ='M'
Group by Customer.hippcode
order by `theater tickets` + `movie tickets` desc;
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select 
    customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email,
    count(case when ticketdetails.eventtype = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as TheaterTickets,
    count(case when ticketdetails.eventtype = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as MovieTickets
from customer
inner join ticketdetails on ticketdetails.hippcode = customer.hippcode
where ticketdetails.hippcode is not null
and ticketdetails.eventType in ('T', 'M')
Group by customer.hippcode, customer.LastName, customer.Firstname, customer.Email
Order by TheaterTickets+MovieTickets desc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! And thanks for the quick response.